# sqlClient with DirectAccess DB connectioin vs Web API

Tags: winforms, asp.net-web-api, architecture, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a legacy WinForm application working with SQLClient connected to SQL DB. It used to work well on a desktop connected to office network through wire. Now, the app is installed on a laptop connected to network through WiFi DirectAccess. The connection failures become a frequent problem. 
In general, the connection errors occur in ADO.Net statements like 
Myconnection.Open(), MyDataTable.Load etc.

I am thinking about moving data layer to restful Web API backend and getting data using HTTPClient in WinForm frontend. However, I am not sure what benefits will be achieved from this approach. Can you please advise what approach is better in terms of resiliency to connection errors, performance and other criteria

1. Develop Web API backend  OR
2. Leave ADO.Net code on the client side as is but improve DB connection error handling and connection resiliency

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a web API backend will also have connectivity errors if the network is not reliable, so you will need retry logic there too.
Adding re-connection logic is a lot cheaper, but obviously having a backend is more scalable.
If this app is the only user I wouldn't build a web api backend, but if you have multiple clients it could become useful

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Do you have any thoughts with regards to the data traffic? What is more efficient to send data through restful web api or using ado.net objects?

Comment: ADO is definitely much faster, Web API would wrap everything in http and that's inherently slow. But in the end it depends on the amount of work yo do on the data, for example if you fetch the data from DB and display summary, the summary would be a lot smaller to send across the network than the data being fetched, so I would absolutely recommend WebAPI if that's how you work with the data.

Comment: In my case, the DB data is not processed neither on client nor server side, i.e. it is used without any changes in front end.  It looks like the only benefit that I can get from web API is the scalability which is not an issue for this WinForm app as the number of users is limited and this app would be the only client of the web API. Is this right? Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, the number of users is actually a number of laptops having this app installed. It is few hundreds.

Comment: pretty much, also security, Web API adds another layer of security, so not everyone has direct access to the database